# Curly quotes from Word in UTF-8 using mb_detect_encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

When detecting the encoding of some text from Word (saved as a CSV file) using...

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, 'WINDOWS-1252, ISO-8859-1', true);
$value = iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $value);
```

If a string has curly quotes the `$encoding` will be set to ISO-8859-1 not WINDOWS-1252 which it should be, so the string will read "self-motivated" with funny boxes around them and not “self-motivated” in it's UTF-8 encoding.

Any ideas on how to resolve this other than replacing the curly quotes, because this could effect other characters too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 only differ in bytes 7F to 9F.  They exist in the former but not in the latter.  If you know your encode is either Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 you can determine which it is by the existence of such bytes.  If no such bytes are included, *and you know it is one of these two encodings*, you can convert from either.

Comment: If I may wax pedantic for a moment, those bytes *do* exist in both encodings; it's just that in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), the characters in that range are seldom-used [C1 control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_character#C1_.28ISO_8859_and_Unicode.29), whereas in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) they are filled with more useful characters such as smart quotes and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I once created a function to convert almost everything to UTF8, it has also some content sniffing functionality inside, may be this helps you?

http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-encode.php#102382